# polynomial even function $f(-x)f(x)$

Tags: minimal-polynomials, even-and-odd-functions

How to prove:

> $f(-x)f(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a function $g(x)$ is symmetric if $g(-x)=g(x)$.

In your case $g(x) = f(-x)f(x)$ and so $g(-x) = f(-(-x))f(-x) = f(x)f(-x) = f(-x)f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: thank you for your help